# java.lang.Exception: No tests found matching [{ExactMatcher:fDisplayName=setReportConfiguration],

Tags: java, maven, automation, bdd, test-runner

I am trying to create a BDD testing Framework and seem to be getting the following error upon running a Testcase from my StepDefinition File.

I have tried adding aopaliance.jar as mentioned on another similar thread, but this didn't work for me. Following is the error:

```
java.lang.Exception: No tests found matching [{ExactMatcher:fDisplayName=setReportConfiguration], {ExactMatcher:fDisplayName=setReportConfiguration(com.web.automation.runner.TestRunner)], {LeadingIdentifierMatcher:fClassName=com.web.automation.runner.TestRunner,fLeadingIdentifier=setReportConfiguration]] from org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest@61a485d2
    at org.junit.internal.requests.FilterRequest.getRunner(FilterRequest.java:40)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createFilteredTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:83)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.loadTests(JUnit4TestLoader.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:513)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:756)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:452)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:210)
```

[image: Step Definition File]

[image: Test Runner file]